# Passing a variable through threaded classes

Tags: python, multithreading

In the test code below,

class1.stop_callback() sets class1.stop = True

therefore class2.stop = True

therefore class3.stop should be True but it isn't.

class1.stop_callback() should stop the program but it doesn't do that.
What am I doing wrong?

You can test the code on repl.it https://repl.it/@bahtsiz_bedevi/classtest

```
import threading
import time


class Class1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False

    def stop_callback(self):
        self.stop = True

    def run(self):
        class2 = Class2()
        class2.stop = self.stop
        class2.start()
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("{} stop status: {}".format(self.__class__, "True" if self.stop else "False"))
            if self.stop:
                break


class Class2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        class3 = Class3()
        class3.stop = self.stop
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("{} stop status: {}".format(self.__class__, "True" if self.stop else "False"))
            if self.stop:
                break
            class3.foo()


class Class3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False

    def foo(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("{} stop status: {}".format(self.__class__, "True" if self.stop else "False"))
            if self.stop:
                break


class1 = Class1()
class1.start()
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
class1.stop_callback()
```

Comment: You are setting `class1.stop` to `True` after you have already copied the value of `class1.stop` to `class2.stop`. Am I overlooking something here? Or did you maybe want to use `class2.stop` as a sort of reference to `class1.stop`?

Comment: What is your desired output, what do you want the program to do?

Comment: @PrestonM "therefore class3.stop should be True but it isn't." that's the problem, output is not important.

Comment: @FlorianRhiem class1.stop_callback() should stop the program but it doesn't do that because class3.foo() doesn't get self.stop=True value

Comment: guys you can test the code here https://repl.it/@bahtsiz_bedevi/classtest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, variables are names for objects. By assigning `False` to `class1.stop` and `class1.stop` to `class2.stop`, you are assigning `False` to `class2.stop`, nothing more.

What you seem to want is a reference to `class1.stop` instead, however this is not how assignment works in Python. One way to get around this would be to use a list. If you keep the list the same and only change the value at the first index, you can achieve what you want:

```
stop1 = [False]
stop2 = stop1
assert stop2[0] == False
stop1[0] = True
assert stop2[0] == True
```

Comment: Inside Class2 there is a line "class3.stop = self.stop", so I am assigning class1.stop to class2.stop to class3.stop

Comment: Please read the first sentence again. By assigning `class1.stop` to `class2.stop`, you are assigning its current value, `False`, to `class2.stop`.

Comment: Now I see :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `Class3` is not a `Thread`-like class (despite not running in the main thread) you cannot change the value of `class3.stop` until `class3.foo()` returns. Since `class3.foo()` doesn't return until the value of `class3.stop` changes, there is no way to stop the process and it runs forever.

I would suggest basing `Class3` on `Thread` so that you can call methods on it while it is running. If this is too much overhead, or you will be running it more than once per instance of `class2`, you could always just define `foo` and then run it within the `Class2.run` method.

---

EDIT: I was going to mention Florian's point, but since - as in his proposed solution - mutable objects *do* carry across during assignments, I wasn't sure if you had already thought this part through.

Below is revised code; note

- the use of `threading.Lock` to prevent those weird print statements that were happening on the same line
- the use of `while not self.stop` rather than `if` statements with `break`s
- the use of threading in `Class3`

---

```
import threading
import time

printLock = threading.Lock()
p = print

def print(*a, **b):
    with printLock:
        p(*a, **b)


class Class1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False

    def stopMe(self):
        self.stop = True

    def run(self):
        class2 = Class2()
        class2.start()
        while not self.stop:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("{} stop status:{:6}".format(self.__class__, str(self.stop)))
        class2.stopMe()


class Class2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False

    def stopMe(self):
        self.stop = True

    def run(self):
        class3 = Class3()
        class3.start()
        while not self.stop:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("{} stop status:{:6}".format(self.__class__, str(self.stop)))
        class3.stopMe()


class Class3(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False

    def stopMe(self):
        self.stop = True

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("{} stop status:{:6}".format(self.__class__, str(self.stop)))


class1 = Class1()
class1.start()
time.sleep(10)
class1.stopMe()
```

Comment: Thanks for the threading.Lock example for print ;)
"the use of while not self.stop rather than if statements with breaks" if stop gets True before While block, it won't be executed. This is not wanted.
"the use of threading in Class3" is not wanted, it has to be not a thread. That was just a sample code :)

Comment: Could you just define `foo` outside of a class structure and then call it from `class2`, rather than instantiating a new object? Also, why can't `Class3` be threaded? Is it acting on something which can't be pickled? And could you do `while True: \n class3.foo()` rather than putting the loop inside `Class3.foo()`? You could define `Class2.stop` and `Class2.stopC3` if other operations are going to stop `class3`. Also, I need to take a breath. (Metaphorically, anyway...)